# Make a choices list for forms.py after receiving data from views.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

So this is the scenario. I allow my user to first input their vehicle brand with one form and then use another form to list down the models available for that vehicle brand. The information on the vehicles and the brands is stored in my database.

Refer to this image to get a better idea:

[image: form screenshot]

And this is my views.py:

```
def driver_dashboard_trip_brand (request, brand):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddVehicleForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = AddVehicleForm()

    brands = VehicleBrand.objects.all()
    context = {
        "form":form,
        "brands":brands,
        "chosen_brand":brand
    }
    return render (request, "app/driver_dashboard.html", context)
```

And my forms.py:

```
class AddVehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=VehicleModel.objects.all())
    vehicle_colour = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOURS)
    vehicle_number = forms.CharField(max_length=8, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'eg: CAB-1234'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['model', 'vehicle_colour', 'vehicle_number']
```

So in order to set a query in the forms.py, I would first need to send the data from views.py to forms.py, and then I also need to do a query.

So my question is how can I query for all the car models from the `VehicleModel` database and create choices attribute for the form, once the user chooses the car brand.

My models.py...

```
class VehicleModel (models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(VehicleBrand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__ (self):
        return f"{self.brand} - {self.model}"
```

Comment: One way you could do that is by using JavaScript to set the attributes of the `model` field in the form. This assumes you are familiar with AJAX....

Comment: oh my....i'm clueless on how to get that done with ajax, is it possible to show me a snippet??

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Answer (score 0):

Its honestly not so hard, i kinda figured it out...

So this is my forms.py...

```
class AddVehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, brand=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddVehicleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['model'].queryset = VehicleModel.objects.filter(brand=brand)

    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=VehicleModel.objects.all())
    vehicle_colour = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOURS)
    vehicle_number = forms.CharField(max_length=8, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'eg: CAB-1234'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['model', 'vehicle_colour', 'vehicle_number']

class AddVehicleFormPost(forms.ModelForm):
    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=VehicleModel.objects.all())
    vehicle_colour = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COLOURS)
    vehicle_number = forms.CharField(max_length=8, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'eg: CAB-1234'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['model', 'vehicle_colour', 'vehicle_number']
```

Where the form `AddVehicleForm` allowed me to send the parameter as shown by typing `form = AddVehicleForm(VehicleBrand.objects.filter(brand=brand).first())` in my views.py, but then when I wanted to save my form I needed to create another form in the forms.py without taking any query which is shown in `AddVehicleFormPost`.

Then i casually did,

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddVehicleFormPost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
```

In my views.py...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a [nice tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) on how to create dependent fields, you need to understand what's going on on the Server, and what's going on on the Client